# React Native - updating Header

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, header

I am using **native-base** for UI and **react-native-router-flux** for navigation.

I have home scene defined as:

```
<Scene key="root" >
        <Scene key="drawer" component={NavigationDrawer} open={false} type={ActionConst.RESET}  hideNavBar={true} >
            <Scene key="home" component={Search}  initial={true}  hideNavBar={true} />
        </Scene>
</Scene>
```

The home scene looks like this:

[image]

I have state variable to see if searchbar should be in header or menu button and search button should be in header.

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            searchActive:false,
        }
    }
}
```

When user clicks on search icon , I update state

```
       const newState=update(this.state,{
            searchActive: {$set: true}
        })
        this.setState(newState);
```

And then in render method I render header according to current state so:

```
 render(){
        const { searchActive} = this.state;

        let header=null;
        if (searchActive) {
            header=<SearchHeader onBack={this.onMenuShow} />
        } else {
            header=<MenuHeader onSearch={this.onSearchShow} />;
        }

        return (
            <Container>
                {header}
                <Content >

                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

The problem is that state is updated,but then something is calling constructor again and mount new home scene and therefore header never change. I suspect **react-native-router-flux** is calling construtor , but I do not understand why???

Comment: If the constructor is getting called again, it is probably because the parent's state changed and it is re-rendering its children.